# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am facing this error. Can I know if there is anything wrong with my code?

```
validateEmail(){
  const emailregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/
  const emailmatch = emailregex.test(this.userObj.user.email)
  if((!emailmatch) || (this.userObj.user.email.length == undefined)){
    this.errors = []
    console.log(this.userObj.user.email)
    this.errors.push("Email is not valid")
  }
```

I am trying to validate an email address using regex

Comment: your regex will say this is valid: `.___.___.@---......`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Probably `this.userObj.user.email` is undefined, try with [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this:

`this.userObj.user.email?.length == undefined`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that your regex is valid, you can check it against some test strings here: https://rubular.com/

This way, you'll eliminate a possible regex bug.